# Please help me Calculate the minimal polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me out to calculate the minimal polynomial of this matrix A where;
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -4\\
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I found the characteristic polynomial as $x^4 - 5x^2 + 4$.

Comment: @postmortes The OP found the characteristic polynomial but it was edited out for some reason by another editor

Comment: @ShubhamJohri wow!  That's a bad edit then :)  I shall delete my comment, thank-you

Comment: Thank you subham sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the characteristic polynomial for the eigenvalues of $A$.$$x^4 - 5x^2 + 4=(x^2-4)(x^2-1)=0\\\implies x=\pm1,\pm2$$Now, recall that the distinct eigenvalues of a matrix are zeroes of its minimal polynomial. So the characteristic polynomial of $A$ divides its minimal polynomial. But the minimal polynomial divides all annihilating polynomials.

This means the minimal polynomial is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I've one more question. How can we determine the characteristic polynomial of this matrix without computing det(xI-A)?

Comment: @PrashantThakuri I'm not aware of any other methods. May be ask that as a separate question or do a quick Google search?